# All links open in div instead of certain links

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap I am working with tabs to load different content in a div an the same page instead of linken with href to a new page.
Working fine, but when I click on a href link somewhere else in the page that content is also loaded in this div instead of functioning as normal href link.

[image]

```
echo '<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/calculaties.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Calculaties</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/offertes.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Offertes / bevestigingen</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/bestellingen.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Bestellingen</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/vrachtbrieven.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Vrachtbrieven</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/facturen.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Facturen</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/producten.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Producten</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/certificaten.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Certificaten</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>';

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load div in click
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});

// Change class on click
$(".clickable").click(function () {
    $('.clickable').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $('.clickable').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });` Why are you removing and adding the same class?

Comment: Well, your code does exactly what you tell it to do : `$('a')` selects _all_ "a" elements in your page.

Comment: @DamienGold OP is removing active from all `clickable` and adding active to the clicked `clickable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this code:

```
echo '<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/calculaties.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="loaddiv">Calculaties</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/offertes.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="loaddiv">Offertes / bevestigingen</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/bestellingen.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="loaddiv">Bestellingen</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/vrachtbrieven.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="loaddiv">Vrachtbrieven</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/facturen.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="loaddiv">Facturen</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/producten.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="loaddiv">Producten</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/certificaten.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="loaddiv">Certificaten</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load div in click
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".loaddiv").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#content").load($(this).attr('href'));
});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Change class on click
 $(".clickable").click(function() {
    $('.clickable').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching click event to all links on the page. Try giving links that should have this behaviour additional class like .hasContent and then target it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.hasContent').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#content").load($(this).attr('href'));
   });
});
```

Edit: As @Derek pointed out, If all links in your menu should work like this then targeting it by wrapper is better approach.

Comment: Simpler solution would be to use a better selector, like `ul.nav > li > a` rather than have to modify the DOM with a class on those `a` tags.

Comment: I would add id to the `.nav` and do a `$('#myId').find('a')` since we are modifying the DOM. It's a much faster.

Comment: @Derek looks like an good idea but in Bootstrap the menus are also based in ul and li.